# Help checking if this variation of the catenary problem makes the curve become a parabola or if it is actually not correct

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics

This is a problem in "Differential Equations: A Modern Approach with Wavelets" by Krantz:

> If the length of any small portion of an elastic cable of uniform density is proportional to the tension in it, then show that it assumes the shape of a parabola when hanging under its own weight.

After not knowing how to approach the problem, I decided to research it and I ended up finding about the [elastic catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Elastic_catenary). And another [source](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/chainette/chainetteelastique.shtml) says that it is a non-algebraic curve, so definitely not a parabola.

Is the problem wrong? or is it that the problem is not that of the elastic catenary?

Comment: You're new, so you don't know.  Titles should refer to the *actual content* of the question, to help users and you find the problem and related ones, particularly through the search tool.  Titles like "Help me solve my problem" contain no information.  Try changing your title.

Comment: Does Krantz provide a solution? If so, can we see it please?

Comment: Cross-posted in physics SE :https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591258/help-checking-if-this-problem-is-correct